# AngularJS : How to add ng-keydown to the first and last element of ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to add ng-keydown to the first and last element of ng-repeat.
How can I do so?

Answer (score 2):

Just use `$first` and `$last` combined with `ng-if`
here example:

```
<ul ng-repeat="n in data">
  <li ng-if="!$first && !$last">{{n.Name}}</li>
  <li ng-if="$first" ng-keydown="something">{{n.Name}} |  first element</li>
  <li ng-if="$last" ng-keydown="something">{{n.Name}} |  last element</li>
</ul>
```

plunker: http://next.plnkr.co/edit/7ptMyWG6lGzvp9jl

More: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <input ng-keypress="example" ng-class='{in:$first}'>
  <input ng-keypress="example" ng-class='{in:$last}'>
</div>
```